These tags are [exception]ally messy
Exception-handling tags are a bit of a mess at the moment. There are a lot of tags that could be used for these sorts of questions. Here are the ones I could find:

exception (~53,000) is an umbrella tag for exceptions in generally, not just for try-catch.
error-handling (~27,000) is another umbrella tag, but more specifically targeted at the handling side, I suppose.

custom-error-handling (199) is specifically the "custom" version of this, which I suppose means "as opposed to automatic"?


try-catch (~8,000) is more specifically about try-catch blocks.

try-catch-finally (441) is basically the same in many languages.
finally (283) is described as "Questions related to the finally block in try-catch construct," so in theory it's just try-catch-finally. In practice, it's used inconsistently to the point of needing disambiguation.
try-finally (186) is...a little weird. In some languages, it's technically a distinct feature from try-catch, but in others, it's the same thing.
catch-block (147) has some pretty significant overlap with the other tags but is also sometimes used to refer to Javascript's Promise.prototype.catch().
try-except (916) is the Python version of try-catch.
do-catch (29) is the same, but for Swift.



A lot of these seem redundant (does every language's version of try-catch need its own tag? is "custom" error handling different from error handling alone?), and it makes it pretty hard to figure out what to use your five tags for or create a sensible custom filter.
I see a few levels of retagging/synonymizing we could do:

Synonymize everything to exception. These tags are all just about exception handling, and the wiki for this tag specifically mentions try/catch syntax, so it might be okay to combine all these tags into one. This is by far the most drastic, though, and I'd worry about losing some nuance.
Synonymize by bullet points - so custom-error-handling becomes a synonym for error-handling, and all the try/catch/finally tags become a synonym of either try-catch or try-catch-finally. This one keeps some of the nuance without the full proliferation of try/catch/finally combinations.

We could also let try-catch-finally, finally, and try-finally have their own tag since they're all specifically about the "finally" part of exception handling.


Just leave it. It's messy, but there are technically distinctions between these tags, so they should all be left separate.

Should we do anything about these tags? If so, how aggressive should we be with the retagging?

Should we also look here on using/try-with-resources blocks as well, since they can be mapped to try-finally code blocks (and I believer the compiler already do)?

I definitely don't see the utility of custom-error-handling over error-handling, so those should be retagged to me. My two cents on the rest is that finally and catch-block are probably not needed (use try-catch-finally and try-catch) (JS's .catch() should be under promise or whatever) but from your descriptions I'm not confident about removing the others.

Synonymize by bullet points - especially try...catch can all be synonymized. There is no real point in having separate tags for this. Exception should preferably be a orphan tag , useable, where other tags don't apply.

"messy" is an understatement. a bunch of those are language-specific, and followers probably expect them to remain that way, so any synonymizing should probably not go overboard. -- I sampled a few of the tags. very low follower count. so perhaps not much impact in dealing with the mess deftly. -- two different opinions? I know that's no help. enjoy :D
